# How do I update background color of the dropdown?

Tags: angular

I am creating a country dropdown using ng add @angular-material-extensions/select-country

Below is my component

```
<mat-select-country appearance="outline"
    label="Country"
    [value]="defaultValue"
    [countries]="predefinedCountries"
    (onCountrySelected)="onCountrySelected($event)">
  </mat-select-country>
```

How do I update the background color of this dropdown?
I have tried mat-option, but it did not work.